# Find all elements by partially matched tag in Python ElementTree using XPath

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath, elementtree

I'm trying to find all heading elements in an XHTML ElementTree, and I was wondering if there is any way to do this with XPath.

```html
<body>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h2>heading 1</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <h3>heading 2</h3>
  <p>text</p>
  <h2>heading 3</h2>
  <p>text</p>
</body>
```

My aim is to get all the heading elements in order, and the naive solution doesn't work:

```py
for element in tree.iterfind("h*"):
  foo(element)
```

Because they should be ordered, I cannot iterate through each heading element individually

```py
headings = {f"h{n}" for n in range(1, 6+1)}

for heading in headings:
  for element in tree.iterfind(heading):
    foo(element)
```

(but `for element in filter(lambda el: el.tag in headings, tree.iterfind())` works)

and I can't use regex because it breaks on comments (which doesn't use string tags)

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile("^h[1-6]$")
is_heading = lambda el: pattern.match(el.tag)

for element in filter(is_heading, tree.iterfind()):
  foo(element)
```

(but `is_heading = lambda el: isinstance(el.tag, str) and pattern.match(el.tag)` works)

None of the solutions are particularly elegant, so I was wondering if there was a better way of finding all heading elements in order using xpath?

Comment: XPath support is limited in ElementTree; are you able to use lxml?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```sh
//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `*` instead of `.`?

Comment: I know ElementTree supports some invalid xpaths, so I did try it and got a `SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element` error (using iterfind like the OP). Maybe you can expand your answer so we don't have to guess how you're able to get an invalid xpath to work?

Comment: It depends of the xpath version. Tried with xpath3. Changed expression to work with xpath1

Comment: Ahh...ElementTree only supports a limited subset of XPath 1.0. so I wasn't thinking of XPath 3.0. (Also, self:: axis isn't supported either unfortunately.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use lxml, you can use the [union operator `|`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets)...

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<body>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h2>heading 1</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <h3>heading 2</h3>
  <p>text</p>
  <h2>heading 3</h2>
  <p>text</p>
</body>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

for elm in tree.xpath("//h1|//h2|//h3"):
    print(elm.text)
```

printed output...

```
title
heading 1
heading 2
heading 3
```

lxml would also allow you to use the `self::` axis like mentioned in another answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html ='''
<body>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h2>heading 1</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <h3>heading 2</h3>
  <p>text</p>
  <h2>heading 3</h2>
  <p>text</p>
</body>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
hs = doc.getElementsByReg('h[1-9]')
print(hs.text)
```

Result:

```
['title', 'heading 1', 'heading 2', 'heading 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should work too:

```
'//*[starts-with(name(), "h") and not(translate(substring(name(),string-length(name())), "0123456789", ""))]'
```